# No of logins per user in Moodle 2.9

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

I am desperately looking at total number of logins on our moodle vle and total number of logins per user. But no lack with this SQL query:

> SELECT concat('',u.firstname ,' ',u.lastname,'') AS Username
>   ,COUNT(*) AS logins
>   ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prefix_log WHERE userid = l.userid GROUP BY userid) AS Activity 
>   FROM prefix_log AS l JOIN prefix_user AS u ON l.userid = u.id 
>   WHERE `action` LIKE '%login%' GROUP BY userid
>   ORDER BY Activity DESC

It is reported at

https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/ad-hoc_contributed_reports#How_many_LOGINs_per_user_and_user.27s_Activity

Since Moodle changed Logging tables since version 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Logging changed in 2.7 - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_2.7_release_notes

The main table is `mdl_logstore_standard_log`

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.firstname, COUNT(*) AS logincount
FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log l
JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = l.userid
WHERE eventname = '\core\event\user_loggedin'
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.firstname
```